# Verify that L'Hopital's rule is of no help in finding the limit , find the limit, if it exists,by some other methods

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

> Verify that L'Hopital's rule is of no help in finding the limit , the find the limit, if it exists,by some other methods $$a-)\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{x+\sin(2x)}{x}$$ $$b-)\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{x(2+\sin(2x))}{x+1}$$

**My work:**

**a-)** It is seen that it is indetermine form of $\infty / \infty$ , so i thought to use L'Hopital rule such that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{1+2\cos(2x)}{1}= \infty$$

According to the L'Hopital rule , if we catch finite or $+\infty,-\infty$ , it is the answer. So , i thought that the answer is $\infty$.However , the answer is $1$ .

**Why cant I use L'Hopital here  ,  why is the answer $1$ instead of $\infty$ ?**

**b-)** The answer is "Limit does not exist " , but i do not understand why the limit "does not exist"

Can you help me ?

Comment: For a), $\cos2x$ has no limit, not even $\pm\infty$, as it's bounded but oscillatory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **a)** note that cosine of whatever argument is between $-1$ and $1$. So I am not sure how you get $\infty$. But since your value varies between $-1$ and $1$, then the limit of the l'Hopital does not exist. But you can split into $$1+\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin2x}x=1+0=1$$
The second limit does not exist for the same reason. Divide both numerator and denominator by $x$. Then the denominator goes to $1$, but the numerator oscillates periodically between $1$ and $3$, so it does not have a limit.